# Flat Join of two tables

Tags: sql, oracle, inner-join

For this two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE TEST1 ( ID  INTEGER ,key  VARCHAR(50),VALUE1 VARCHAR(50));
CREATE TABLE TEST2 ( ID  INTEGER ,key  VARCHAR(50),VALUE2 VARCHAR(50));
```

Table1:

```
130,    'HANSEN',   'STREET1'
130,    'HANSEN',   'STREET2'
130,    'HANSEN',   'STREET3'
120,    'HANSEN',   'STREET5'
120,    'HANSEN',   'STREET6'
```

Table2:

```
130,    'HANSEN',   'ZIP1'
130,    'HANSEN',   'ZIP2'
130,    'HANSEN',   'ZIP3'
120,    'HANSEN',   'ZIP4'
120,    'HANSEN',   'ZIP5'
```

Is it possible to get the output as:

```
130,    'HANSEN',   'ZIP1','STREET1'
130,    'HANSEN',   'ZIP2','STREET2'
130,    'HANSEN',   'ZIP3','STREET3'
120,    'HANSEN',   'ZIP4','STREET5'
120,    'HANSEN',   'ZIP5','STREET6'
```

Tried with inner join on id,key but i get the Cartesian product

Thanks for your help.

Helper script (if someone is willing to test it):

```
DROP TABLE TEST1;
DROP TABLE TEST2;

CREATE TABLE TEST1 ( ID  INTEGER ,key  VARCHAR(50),VALUE1 VARCHAR(50));
CREATE TABLE TEST2 ( ID  INTEGER ,key  VARCHAR(50),VALUE2 VARCHAR(50));

INSERT INTO TEST1 VALUES (130,  'HANSEN',   'STREET1');
INSERT INTO TEST1 VALUES (130,  'HANSEN',   'STREET2');
INSERT INTO TEST1 VALUES (130,  'HANSEN',   'STREET3');
INSERT INTO TEST1 VALUES (120,  'HANSEN',   'STREET5');
INSERT INTO TEST1 VALUES (120,  'HANSEN',   'STREET6');

INSERT INTO TEST2 VALUES (130,  'HANSEN',   'ZIP1');
INSERT INTO TEST2 VALUES (130,  'HANSEN',   'ZIP2');
INSERT INTO TEST2 VALUES (130,  'HANSEN',   'ZIP3');
INSERT INTO TEST2 VALUES (120,  'HANSEN',   'ZIP4');
INSERT INTO TEST2 VALUES (120,  'HANSEN',   'ZIP5');
```

Comment: @Vash: no, it's not a cartesian join. Apparently OP needs a join on ROW NUMBER. It might be done, depending on RDBMS.

Comment: @Vash: The desired output is not Cartesian join

Comment: You just illustrated that you wanted two columns: one for street, and the 2nd for zip. The comma being the separator for columns. `'ZIP1','STREET1'`

Comment: @PabloSantaCruz, true i removed the comment ASAP. But was to slow for you. The row number is good hint.

Comment: How do you know which row from `TEST1` to match to which row in `TEST2`?  Why does `STREET1` get matched with `ZIP1` and not `ZIP2`?  Or does it matter which rows (with the same `ID`) get matched together?  What happens if one or the other table has more rows for a particular `ID` than the other?

Comment: Hmm.. relational database is set-based, there's no notion of rows position. Even it can be done, it look arbitrary to join rows based on row position / row number. Perhaps the database need redesign?

Comment: Might as well write it like this: `select id, "key", value1, 'ZIP' || rownum as value2 from test1;`

Comment: +1 for supplying the DDL and DML

Comment: >>> Perhaps the database need redesign? >>> indeed.. unfortunately its a legacy system..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
with t1 as (
    select id, 
           key, 
           value1,
           row_number() over (partition by id order by key, value1) as rn
    from test1
), 
t2 as (
    select id, 
           key, 
           value2,
           row_number() over (partition by id order by key, value2) as rn
    from test2
)
select t1.id, 
       t2.key, 
       t2.value2||','||t1.value1
from t1
  join t2 on t1.id = t2.id and t1.key = t2.key and t1.rn = t2.rn
order by 1 desc, 3 asc
```

Comment: @user648026: Show us the explain plan. Which indexes are defined on the tables?

Comment: Select XXX from test2,Select XXX from test1 - will create FULL TABLE ACCESS correct? unless you have index on ID..

Comment: @user648026: an index on `id, key, value` might help as well.

Answer (score 1):

It's not pretty, and you might get weird results depending on the order Oracle gives you the result set, but you can try:

```
select t1.id, t1.key, t1.value1, t2.value2 
  from
     (select rownum rn, id, key, value1 from test1) t1 
          inner join
     (select rownum rn, id, key, value2 from test2) t2
          using (rn)
```

If you need to "merge" the two tables as you are suggesting, I would try to add some "merge" column to do so and not using this approach.

Comment: @user648026: Oh, yes! It's dangerous indeed.

Answer (score 0):

No..  there is no way to reliably get the output you desire.

it looks like your datamodel is missing some information.  ie some way to link the rows from test 1 to test 2.. the id/key you have at the moment is not unique enough.

i think the best you could do as it stands would be

```
select *
from test1 
inner join test2 using (id,key)
order by 1 desc,2,3,4
```

which gives the output of

```
130 HANSEN  STREET1 ZIP1
130 HANSEN  STREET1 ZIP2
130 HANSEN  STREET1 ZIP3
130 HANSEN  STREET2 ZIP1
130 HANSEN  STREET2 ZIP2
130 HANSEN  STREET2 ZIP3
130 HANSEN  STREET3 ZIP1
130 HANSEN  STREET3 ZIP2
130 HANSEN  STREET3 ZIP3
120 HANSEN  STREET5 ZIP4
120 HANSEN  STREET5 ZIP5
120 HANSEN  STREET6 ZIP4
120 HANSEN  STREET6 ZIP5
```